# Using python to search a website and return results

Tags: python

I would like to be able to search a website (http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/forms/nearname.html) with python and return a selection of values with the search. I want to use python and would like to know what literature to search for examples, and so I can learn how to do it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good places to start include the [`Requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).